# Altering PWM on four pin fans using only transistors

Tags: pwm, control, npn, fan, speed

I have some high RPM 4 pin Tacho PWM fans, they run at 6000RPM and 56.5 DB at 100% duty cycle the noise is enough to drive you insane - there are seven of them total running off of a SAS backplane, they absolutely do not need to be running this fast but the speed control values are burnt into firmware on the backplane.

I have experimented with one of them and found that noise is virtually eliminated by running them at 2400 to 2600RPM and they still push quite a reasonable amount of air.

What I am wanting to do is continue using the hard coded values being feed out to the fans and have all signals operating as normal so that the backplane does not know that anything has changed and thinks that what it is feeding out is actually what is happening but at the same time use NPN transistors to reduce the PWM signal down to the levels mentioned while still returning faked correct values to the backplane.

I am not offay with electronics and I think this acheivable, I would like to keep it as simple as possible as there is no way on this or any other planet that I would be able to surface mount components my skills with soldering and my steadiness aren't that great.

Can someone please help me out with what I need to do to acheive this.

TIA.

Comment: Altering PWM is more complicated than you'd think. Are you sure you can't use something like speedfan to adjust it?

Comment: There is no PC in this system it is only a disk chassis with two chained SAS backplanes, the values for fan control are burnt into firmware and I have no way of being able to identify what byte values in the firmware relate to the control of the fans, only that the fans have 3 modes which they can switch between with permanently fixed values.

Comment: Well, you *can* do this but it's likely more complicated than you want. I'd use a microcontroller with PWM output and low-pass filter the fan controller's PWM, measure it with an ADC, and use that to control your new PWM fan curve. Then you'd also have to fake the feedback signal doing the same thing in reverse, I think. Might be easier to just turn off the built-in fan controller and make your own. Are you sure the fan controller doesn't have any settings? Have you looked up a datasheet for it?

Comment: I checked the documentation for the SAS backplane, it states that the fans controlled by the backplane have the values for 3 modes hard coded, beyond that you have two jumpers involved, 1) disable the fan headers on the SAS backplane completely 2) disable the fan alarm.

Comment: Would it not be possible to use NPN transistors and for every two pulses sent only send one to the fan and bothe the 1/2 signal result and the full signal result back to the origionating fan header?

Comment: I guess you could do a divide-by-two, but how would you get the feedback back? the fan's going to be reporting it's going at half speed, so you'll need to double its PWM. You can do that with a phase-locked loop, but we're out of the range of basic circuits you can make with discrete transistors here.